# Pistache: how to set TCP server options, for example SO_REUSEADDR

Tags: c++, sockets, server

I'm starting to do some tests with Pistache, and I'd like to know how to set TCP options. Like in the example below, I'd like to set `SO_REUSEADDR` to the server socket.

```
#include <pistache/endpoint.h>

using namespace Pistache;

struct HelloHandler : public Http::Handler {
  HTTP_PROTOTYPE(HelloHandler)
  void onRequest(const Http::Request&, Http::ResponseWriter writer) override{
    writer.send(Http::Code::Ok, "Hello, World!");
  }
};

int main() {
  Http::listenAndServe<HelloHandler>(Pistache::Address("*:9080"));
}
```

Comment: I found `pistache::Tcp::setSocketOptions`, that might do what you need.

Comment: AFAICS, `pistache::Tcp::setSocketOptions()` is private to the implementation, you can't call it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listenAndServe()` has an optional `options` parameter, and the `Options` class has a `ReuseAddr` flag defined (and a `ReusePort` flag), eg:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto opts = Http::Endpoint::options();
    opts.flags(Tcp::Options::ReuseAddr);
    // set other options as needed...
    Http::listenAndServe<HelloHandler>(Pistache::Address("*:9080"), opts);
}
```